# Tkinter Python - Converting an image to black and white

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

I am still trying to figure out how to convert an image to black and white.

I have a GUI with a command button that says "convert image to black and white". I bind that command to `def bAndW(self)`. It loads the current image on GUI but does not convert to black and white.

Below is the code:

```
def bAndW(self):

    from images import Image

    LoadAFile = self.inputText.getText()
    CurrentImage = open(LoadAFile)
    image = Image(LoadAFile)
    image.draw()
    BlackAndWhite(image)
    image.draw()
    #self.imageLabel["image"] = self.image


def BlackAndWhite(image):       
      
    blackPixel = (0,0,0)
    whitePixel = (255,255,255)
    
    for y in range(image.getHeight()):
        for x in range(image.getWidth()):
            (r, g, b) = image.getPixel(x,y)
            average = (r + b + g) /3
            if average < 128:
                image.setPixel(x,y,blackPixel)
            else:
                image.setPixel(x,y, whitePixel)
```

This is the error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/movio/Desktop/CSCI/P6.1.py", line 50, in bAndW
    BlackAndWhite(image)
NameError: name 'BlackAndWhite' is not defined
```

Comment: If `BlackAndWhite()` is a function inside same class, `self.BlackAndWhite(image)` should be used.  Also `def BlackAndWhite(self, image)` should be used as well.

Comment: I believe PIL has a function to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As acw1668 said,

> If BlackAndWhite() is a function inside same class,
> self.BlackAndWhite(image) should be used. Also def BlackAndWhite(self,
> image) should be used as well

This should solve your error.
Also, instead of writing your own function for converting an image into black and white, you can make use of the PILLOW library which provides you with a simple function to do so.

```py
from PIL import Image

    def bAndW(self):
        LoadAFile = "image_to_open.png"
        img = Image.open(LoadAFile)
        img.convert("L")
```

Here, the `convert()` method converts the image into a grayscale (black and white) image.

Comment: According to OP code, OP wants real black and white (ie two colors only) image.  So `convert("1")` should be used instead.